# less support for sitecore

Tags: less, sitecore, sitecore7, dotless

I use DOTLESS (http://www.dotlesscss.org/) for normal .net projects to work with LESS css .

like this DOTLESS is a .NET port for LESS, is there anything like this from SITECORE to support less in sitecore projects?

Comment: As CSS and LESS are not content that should be managed within sitecore you should be setting up a less compiler, such as dotLess or the standard node less command, to execute as part of a build process.

Comment: Not sure why this question was flagged as off-topic, seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Though CSS and LESS are not content, sometimes requirements are to manipulate styles from CMS side, so that a business user can manipulate styles( like link colors, bg images etc...).